# Use a cell value in VBA function with a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to `VBA` and I can't manage to do what I want although it's very simple.

I need to automatically modify cells of a big (333x333) empty (full of zeros) spreadsheet.

In a separate spreadsheet I have the row and column of all the cells to modify. (5000 of them)

A `for` loop seems to be suited for this purpose.

Here is the code of my macro. The problem appears on the line before the last one.

```
Dim val1 As String, val2 As String, i As Integer

For i = 1 To 333

  Sheets("Feuil2").Activate
  ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Select

    val1 = Cells(i, 1).Value
    val2 = Cells(i, 2).Value

Sheets("Classeur2.csv").Select
Cells(val1, val2).Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"

Next i
```

The line that causes a problem is this one : Cells(val1, val2).Select

I believe my error is a syntax error. But I can't find out what I should add before, after or around my two variables "val1" and "val2"

What do you think ?

Thanks a lot for your help.
Nicolas.

**Edit**

My problem is now solved :

The first answer is exactly what I needed to male my macro work.
The second answer is the proper and faster way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to activate or selection sheets or cells if you're using VBA. You can access it all directly.
The code:

```
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In Sheets("Feuil2").Range("A1:A333")
    Sheets("Classeur2.csv").Cells(rng.Value, rng.Offset(, 1).Value) = "1"
Next rng
```

is producing the same result as Joe's code.

If you need to switch sheets for some reasons, use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of your macro (and `Application.ScreenUpdating=True` at the end). This will remove the screenflickering - and speed up the execution.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that's good to know. I'll give it a try next time.

Comment: Well, I owe you a big thank you ! Today I had to scale my macro to consider 5000 lines. It took more than 20 minuts to go through the first 3000 lines. I know it because I had to stop the macro and try your solution. I used these 20 minuts to understand the "Range" notation. It way faster (about a minut now).

Comment: You can speed it even further by inserting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`! At the end of the macro, reset it with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` :-)

Comment: Just realized I already mentioned the ScreenUpdating in the answer... :-/

Answer (score -1):

VAL1 and VAL2 need to be dimmed as integer, not as string, to be used as an argument for Cells, which takes integers, not strings, as arguments.

```
Dim val1 As Integer, val2 As Integer, i As Integer

For i = 1 To 333

  Sheets("Feuil2").Activate
  ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Select

    val1 = Cells(i, 1).Value
    val2 = Cells(i, 2).Value

Sheets("Classeur2.csv").Select
Cells(val1, val2).Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"

Next i
```

Comment: You also might try that loop as a FOR EACH loop.  Not a big difference but a bit easier to read.